# unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND error in my if statement

Tags: php, facebook, if-statement

I have the following IF statement:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php') === strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) - strlen('/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php') ) {
    $style = "display: inline";
}
else {
  $style = "display: none";
}
```

This works great. Now I wanted to show a Facebook login screen when `$style = "display:inline";`

So I figured, I make another IF with an AND, so IF display = inline AND user is NOT logged in, set `$fb_login = "display: inline";`

I've cooked up this code:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php') === strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) - strlen('/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php') ) {
    $style = "display: inline";
}
else {
  $style = "display: none";
}

if ($style = "display: inline") && (!$user)) {
    $fb_login = "display: inline";
}
else {
    $fb_login = "display: none";
}
```

Problem is I get an error with this: **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND

Also tried to use AND instead of && but it gave the same result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your assignment operator (`=`) should be a comparison operator (`==`)
- There was an unneeded parenthesis (`)`)
- I also removed some unnecessary brackets around the 2nd condition

```
if ($style == "display: inline" && !$user) {
    $fb_login = "display: inline";
}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it, I thought the double (( where needed but I see I can leave them out. Didn't know that!

Also to all others who suggested: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `(`

```
if (($style == "display: inline") && (!$user)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a bracket on this line

```
if ($style = "display: inline") && (!$user)) {
```

It should be

```
if (($style == "display: inline") && (!$user)) {
```

But you should ask yourself if you should approach this a different way. The code you've got is very specific to the output and you might be better for maintainability reasons doing your logic first then your display. Something like this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php') === strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) - strlen('/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php') ) {
    $mahjongRequest = true;
}
else {
    $mahjongRequest = false;
}

if ($mahjongRequest && (!$user)) {
    $fb_login = true;
}
else {
    $fb_login = false;
}
```

Also, you might want to review your initial IF statement. It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve and there may be a much simpler, more-readable way to do it.

Comment: Got it fixed thanks. The code is indeed specific and should only fire if the exact url is loaded.

Comment: @Maurice Any reason you're not just comparing the REQUEST_URI to your expected URI directly? Using strpos and strlen seems an awfully complicated way to go about it.

Comment: Yes this game I am building has a start menu which needs to be shown at the moment you load the game, (which you load when going to the mahjong.php file). Problem is, there is a random layout build in, that loads a random layout when loading mahjong.php. This I don't want, so I "override" this by loading a div over it (style: inline) when loading this .php file and so showing the menu. Since I am just starting to learn php this is the best way I can think of to do this. I think there is a better solution, but I am not there yet to tackle this :)

Comment: It was the first conditional I was really talking about, can it not just be: if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/dev/mahjong/mahjong.php' )